# Trouble in restricting the directory which contains .htaccess file

Tags: apache, security, .htaccess

When I try to access the `.htaccess` file, Apache says access is forbidden, which is obvious. But the listing of all other files is also getting displayed, i.e no restrictions are imposed on those files which are under the same directory as the `.htaccess`. However I want to restrict everyone but myself from those files too. Here is my httpd.config:

Inside directory of `httpd.config`:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

AllowOverride ALL

Require all granted

<Files ".ht*">
  Require all denied
</Files>
```

My `.htaccess` file:

```
# deny everyone but myself
<Limit GET POST PUT>
    Options -Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Limit>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instructions in your `.htaccess` file do not allow access to *anyone*. If you want to restrict everyone *but yourself*, you need to add an `Allow` section and describe how to allow yourself in.

Comment: That's right. I could add "ALLLOW FROM xxx.xx.xx.x" when i have a static ip address. But unfortunately i don't have one,So is there any way using php we can grab the current ip address and auto set it in .htaccess?